# is it possible to add the 'values' of a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is it possible to add the 'values' of a dictionary? I'm trying to make it so my program asks for input, and if that input matches the 'keys' of the dictionary, it then adds the values of the keys together. Currently, my code will return the value of a single key that is input, but if the user inputs multiple, it returns a 0

I also then want to provide feedback to the user, so if they are missing some of the 'keys' in the dictionary, it will tell them what keys they are missing, and the value of those keys.

Here is what i have so far:

```
skills = {
        "python": 1,
        "ruby": 2,
        "bash":  4,
        "git": 8,
        "html": 16,
        "tdd": 32,
        "css": 64,
        "javascript": 128
    }
    

user_skills = input("Enter your coding skills out of the folllowing - python, ruby, bash, git, html, tdd, css and javascript: ")


score = 0

for key, value in skills.items():
    if key == user_skills:
        score = value + score

print("Your coding skills score is:") 
print(score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when the user inputs multiple keys (assuming separated by spaces, for example), Python will simply consider this as one string and not multiple. So if the user inputs `python ruby css`, your program will then check whether this **whole** string appears as a key inside your dictionary, which it does not (hence why you get `0`).

To fix this, you want to tell Python to "break down" the string every time there is a whitespace. For this, you use the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function.

```py
skills = {
    "python": 1,
    "ruby": 2,
    "bash":  4,
    "git": 8,
    "html": 16,
    "tdd": 32,
    "css": 64,
    "javascript": 128
}

# We split the string at every whitespace
user_skills = input("Enter your coding skills out of the folllowing - python, ruby, bash, git, html, tdd, css and javascript: ").split()

score = 0

for key, value in skills.items():
    if key in user_skills: # We use 'in' to check whether the key appears in the list of user skills provided by the user
        score = value + score

print("Your coding skills score is:") 
print(score)
```

Now, if you input `python ruby css`, you should get `67` as requested.

To answer the below comment, here is how you can print the missing skills:

```py
skills = {
    "python": 1,
    "ruby": 2,
    "bash":  4,
    "git": 8,
    "html": 16,
    "tdd": 32,
    "css": 64,
    "javascript": 128
}

user_skills = input("Enter your coding skills out of the folllowing - python, ruby, bash, git, html, tdd, css and javascript: ").split()

score = 0

for key, value in skills.items():
    if key in user_skills:
        score += value
    else:
        print("Missing:", key, ":", value, "points")

print("Your coding skills score is:") 
print(score)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was so close.
Any hints on how to now print what 'skills' the user is missing, and their associated 'score' ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the sum() function with a comprehension instead of a loop:

```
score = sum(skills.get(skill,0) for skill in user_skills.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` instead of `==`, like

```
if key in user_skills:
```

That's all you need to change in your code.

You might also like to use an f-string though:

```
print(f"Your coding skills score is: {score}")
```

or, if you actually want the newline:

```
print(f"Your coding skills score is:\n{score}")
```